# Why "result" and "current" doesn't give the same output though they are mentioned as the same in this code?

Tags: python, dictionary

Are there dictionary's properties I don't catch?

```
List = [1, 2, 3, 4]
result = current = {}
for n in List:
    current[n] = {}
    current = current[n]

print(current)
print(result)
```

output1:  {}

output2:  {1: {2: {3: {4: {}}}}}

Comment: Each iteration through the loop you set `current` to be a new empty dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially in your code you point both `current` and `result` to the same memory location. However in every loops iteration you change the memory location that `current` points to by reassigning it to a new empty dictionary for the keys iterated through the list.

At the end of the loop:

```
{1: {2: {3: {4: {}}}}}
^               ^
|               |
|               |
|             current point here
|     
result points here
```

Hence explaining the outputs that you are receiving

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @OsamuZenji If this answer helped you, kindly mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned earlier, it's a simple memory allocation issue. Python uses dynamic memory allocation hence the problem.

A simple fix would be -

```
List = [1, 2, 3, 4]
result = {}
current = {}
for n in List:
    current[n] = {}
    current = current[n]

print(current)
print(result)
```

Comment: Got it! Also I suspect that. You make me clear.

Comment: Great ! Do consider marking this as the answer ! :)